# which .NET API will allow me to programmatically rename the contents of a zip file without having to unzip and re-zip the zip file?

Tags: .net, api, zip

I'm looking for a .NET open source API that will allow me to open a zip file (without actually extracting its contents), get a list of files, and then rename them, all without having to unzip and re-zip the zip file.

Is there such an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DotNetZip - http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

You can edit the Filename property of a ZipEntry.

Comment: I already have it. It doesn't look like it's capable of doing that.

Comment: Yes it is, read the documentation: http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DNZHelp/html/913abfd3-bbc6-803c-858b-f53dfb008e55.htm - All you need to do is change the Filename property of each ZipEntry.

Comment: It really doesn't help me. I can use the "Entries" property of the ZipFile object, which returns an ICollection<ZipEntry> object, each ZipEntry object has a "FileName" property, but I cannot modify it programmatically without getting an exception because the collection was modified. The idea is to mass rename everything. I don't know the filenames beforehand.

Comment: Do `.ToList()` on the `ICollection<ZipEntry>` - then you can safely modify it while iterating over it, either that or iterate by index instead of using `foreach`.

Comment: ICollection does not have a ToList() method. It doesn't have an indexer either, so using a for loop won't help either.

Comment: `.ToList()` is an extension method. You need `using System.Linq` to use it. You can also use `.ToArray()` - in either case the zip API lets you do it, you've just got to figure out how to use it.

Comment: not using .NET 3.5+, so I have no LINQ. Anyway, I solved the problem by adding each ZipEntry to a ZipEntry[] array and then modifying the values within the array. Thanks for your help.